# How can I override the default prefix when loading an ontology from file?

Tags: rdf, ontology, jena

I have created an ontology with RDFS, using relative URIrefs to save keystrokes. Now, I want to load the ontology with Jena and use it to structure my data. However, when I read the file in with `m.read("file:flow-schema.rdf");` and display it with `m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV", "http://flowschema/#");`, the relative URIrefs are prefixed with `file:flow-schema.rdf`, not `http://flowschema/#`. How can I change the default prefix for an ontology loaded from a file?

Here's my ontology file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">]>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:base="http://flowschema/#">

<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Flow" />
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="srcIP">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Flow" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal" />
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="dstIP">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Flow" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal" />
</rdf:Property>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Here's the Java code that reads the ontology from a file:

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM);
m.read("file:flow-schema.rdf");
m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV", "http://flowschema/#");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to have tried to set the Base URI in your RDF/XML but you've used `xmlns:base` which is incorrect usage.  To set the Base URI you must use `xml:base`, what you have done is define an additional namespace `base` rather than define the Base URI.

Change that part of your RDF/XML and then it should work fine without needing the workarounds others have suggested.

Your current write code ends up with incorrect URIs because Jena has already automatically generated absolute URIs using the file URI as a base.  Setting a Base URI for writing has no effect if the URIs in the RDF are not perceived to be under that Base URI as far as Jena is concerned.

**Note:**
RDF generally requires absolute URIs, relative URIs are a serialization convenience that can help compress the syntax.  If you use relative URIs you **should** always specify the Base URI explicitly if the syntax permits this and if not use absolute URIs instead.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [read(String url, String base, String lang)](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) by specifying the base URI instead of `read(String url)` ? ?

Answer (score 2):

Jena internally uses full URIs for everything. That's why you have to specify the base URI at load time. Specifying it at write time only doesn't have the desired effect. As Pierre said, this should work:

```
m.read("file:flow-schema.rdf", "http://flowschema/#", "RDF/XML");
```